# Radius of convergence of $\sqrt{\sin(z)/z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying find an analytic definition for $f(z)=\sqrt{z \sin(z)}$ around $0$ ( i.e. $f$ such that $f^2(x) = z \sin(z)$ .) If I write $z \sin(z) = z^2 \frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ then I may take the definition to be $f(z) =z \sqrt{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}}$ using the standard branch of $\sqrt{z}$ since $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ is away from $0$ for small $z$.

**For a power series around $0$ of $f(z)$ defined as such, what is the radius of convergence?**

It definitely needs to be less than $\pi$ since $f'(z)$ becomes unbounded near $\pi$, but could it be strictly less?

Also, is there another way to define $f$ so that I can get a bigger radius of convergence?

Comment: The radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest singularity or branch point, in your case that's $\pi$.

Comment: You just have to make sure that your function is well-defined within $B(0,π)$, so you need $\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ to stay away from the negative real line so that you can use the standard branch of $\sqrt{z}$. It is not enough for it to be away from zero.

Comment: @user21820 The disk is simply connected, so $\frac{\sin z}{z} \neq 0$ suffices for the existence of $\sqrt{\frac{\sin z}{z}}$ on the disk.

Comment: I have not learned about the theory of branch points yet. Why is $\pi$ a branch point? And why are there no other branch points which are closer? And might there be a different definition with different branch points?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Your reasoning is a different way to define the function desired, but my objection stands because Mark defined his function using the **standard branch** of the square-root function.

Comment: @Mark: Daniel's justification is one way to find the radius of convergence, namely that a branch of $\sqrt{}$ can be defined on any simply connected region that does not include $0$, by first defining a branch of $\ln$ using a path integral of $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ (which is why you need the region not to contain $0$), which will be independent of the path because of Cauchy-Goursat's theorem. This shows that $B(0,π)$ works.

Comment: At the same time, any open region containing $0$ cannot have a holomorphic $\sqrt{}$ because its argument on a circle around $0$ within the region would be differentiable with respect to the argument of the input, which would mean that winding once round the circle increases the argument of the output by π, which is impossible.

Comment: We do not know that the image $\{\sin(z)/z | z \in \pi D\}$ is simply connected, do we?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if your post also asks for the construction of the power series of $$f(z)=\sqrt{z \sin(z)}$$ So, if it is off topis, let me know and I shall delete my answer.

Start from the expansion of $$\sin(z)\simeq z\Big(1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}\Big)$$ So,$$f(z)=\sqrt{z \sin(z)}\simeq z \sqrt { 1-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}}$$ Now, consider $$\sqrt{1+y} \simeq 1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}$$ and replace in this last expression $$y=-\frac{z^2}{6}+\frac{z^4}{120}$$ to end with $$f(z)=\sqrt{z \sin(z)} \simeq z-\frac{z^3}{12}+\frac{z^5}{1440}$$ which is an exremely good approximation up to $z \simeq 2$.

If you go further in the expansions, you should find  $$f(z)=\sqrt{z \sin(z)}=z-\frac{z^3}{12}+\frac{z^5}{1440}-\frac{z^7}{24192}-\frac{67
   z^9}{29030400}-\frac{z^{11}}{5677056}+O\left(z^{13}\right)$$

Comment: I wanted to know what is the radius of convergence of this series